# PHP doesn't see locales installed on the server

Tags: php, apache, locale

ubuntu 13, php 5.5.3

when I run "locale -a" from root console I get the following list:

```
C
C.UTF-8
de_AT.utf8
de_BE.utf8
de_CH.utf8
de_DE
de_DE@euro
de_DE.iso88591
de_DE.iso885915@euro
de_DE.utf8
de_LI.utf8
de_LU.utf8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

but when i run

> system("locale -a")

from PHP I receive another list:

```
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
af_ZA.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
```

what can I make my PHP see German locales installed on the server?

ps: apache is running under `www-data` user.

thanks in advance

Comment: is apache running in a chroot environment?

Comment: no. it doesn't run in chroot

Comment: What gives you `diff -u <(sudo -u www-data locale -a) <(locale -a)` ?  (executed in the console)

Comment: it gives nothing.. but when i run 
sudo -u www-data locale -a
i get the following list


af_ZA.utf8
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX

Comment: and it differs from the one i get running the same command under root

Comment: `and it differs from the one i get running the same command under root`. The the `diff` command should show this. isn't it? However, have a look at the `$LOCPATH` environment variable. It points to the locale database location. Maybe this has been changed? Btw, is this a vanilla system setup by yourself? Or is it likely that other admins changed something?

Comment: there's also nginx on this server running as proxy for all php requests

Comment: NO. The command returns no output at all. probably there's a mistake?

Comment: No. No mistake in the command. However, this might us not get closer to the problem's cause but have you tried `sudo locale-gen de_DE.UTF8` ?

Comment: sure.

and i've just found a strange folder /var/lib/locales/supported.d
with 3 files : en, af and local

e.g. "en" contains the list i've seen in www-data's output: 

en_HK.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_DK.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_IN UTF-8
en_ZM UTF-8
en_ZW.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_NZ.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_PH.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_NG UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_AU.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_SG.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_BW.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_AG UTF-8
en_ZA.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_CA.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_IE.UTF-8 UTF-8

Comment: btw: $LOCPATH has the following line:
declare -x PWD="/var/lib/locales/supported.d"

Comment: in this case i can't understand where does root user get the list of locales from

Comment: I guess $LOCPATH is configured in root's bashrc?

Comment: no, can't find it neither there nor in .profile

Comment: (r)grep for it it must be somewhere

Comment: can't find it anywhere. there are not too many files to miss it with grep ..

but.. don't know what exactly made this effect.. but now i see only "local" file in "/var/lib/locales/supported.d" 
and it contains the correct list of locales.. but apache still sees the wrong list.

Comment: i did try to restart it but got no effect

Comment: sorry guys. my fail. i've got this problem fixed. thanks for your help

Comment: And what was the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

mark all you need. then restart php-fpm (if you use fpm) or simply reboot system.
you'll be able to use any of listed with `locales -a`